Next.js application build Error with '/seed collection failed'||vercel deploy failed
I'm learning on the Next.js Website, and now I have learned Chapter 6 the title is "setting up your database". and then when I was deploying my next application or excute "pnpm run build", an error occurred.
  Collecting page data  ..tl [VercelPostgresError]: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.
    at tf (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/app/seed/route.js:60:5026)
    at Object.get (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/app/seed/route.js:60:6072)
    at /Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/app/seed/route.js:1:3983
    at t.a (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:866)
    at 1507 (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/app/seed/route.js:1:3876)
    at t (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
    at /Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/app/seed/route.js:1:1176
    at t.a (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:866)
    at 1193 (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/app/seed/route.js:1:967)
    at t (/Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127) {
  code: 'missing_connection_string'
}

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /seed
    at /Users/muyi/Desktop/web/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.0-rc.0_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f994737d14-20240522_react@19.0.0-rc-f994737d14-20240522/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1274:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
   Collecting page data  . ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

please,how can I fix this problem so that my app can deploy succsses?
I tried to redeploy my app on the Vercel website but it failed, the same problem still exists.

The error message you're encountering indicates that the connectionString for your PostgreSQL database is missing. Specifically, the POSTGRES_URL environment variable is not set, and the application cannot connect to the database without it.
Solution:
Set Up Environment Variables:
Ensure that you have the correct environment variables set up in your project. You need to set the POSTGRES_URL environment variable with your database connection string.
